# Array of boolean lambda loop

Tags: java

Basically we have an array of booleans to check if something is activated or not, is there a way to convert the for loop into a lambda / arrays#stream function?

```
private final static boolean[] normal = new boolean[29];

private static final int CONFIG = 630;

for (int i = 0; i < normal.length; i++) {
            if (normal[i]) {
                sendConfig(CONFIG + i, 1);
    }
}
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you're accessing the index of your array, it's idiotic to try convert it to a lambda, because you lose that information

Comment: @bubletan answered my question, you yourself are idiotic.

Comment: I never said it was impossible. I just said it was idiotic. Small but quite significant difference. There is no need ot convert every single for loop ever in your code to lambdas just because "lambdas"...

Comment: @JasonQlueses Vogel is right here. There is absolutely no point in creating a lambda. All you're doing is trading 1/2 lines of code for more overhead. No need to call someone idiotic either.

Comment: You were so preoccupied with whether or not you could that you forgot to think about whether or not you should ... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need the index, the only way I could think of is using `IntStream` like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, normal.length)
        .filter(i -> normal[i])
        .forEach(i -> sendConfig(CONFIG + i, 1));
```

Comment: ...that was awesome; though I'm sure the `for`-loop is way faster

Comment: Just because you can actually do that, that doesn't mean you should... I think this "solution" is losing incredibly much expressivity when compared against the plain old for-loop it replaces. Instead of mindlessly feeding people solutions to dumb questions ... eh well.

Comment: @Vogel612 I wouldn't say so. Even if normal for-loop is performance-wise better and such, there is still the syntactical side which is some case might be better using lambdas. In this specific case there is no big difference and I personally wouldn't use the approach given in my answer... But I still decided to post it as it answers to the question.